# can 'no-unbound-method' be whitelisted for unittests? Is there any possibility of me facing an issue in future because of whitelisting

Tags: angularjs, typescript, tslint

Example:

```
class MyClass {
  public log(): void {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

unittests.js

```
const instance = new MyClass();
expect(instance.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Avoid referencing unbound methods error has been thrown while tried to unit test. Is it better to go with arrow functions rather than adding a 'whitelist' option in linting. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 11):

TypeScript flags this because your original function references `this`. Note that TypeScript doesn't know about jest, and the mock or spy that (presumably) you're using to track calls.

The way I've addressed this is to **name the mock** and reference it directly, so that TypeScript and jest can agree on the mock's type.

In your example, where we are spying on an existing method, we name the spy:

```js
const instance = new MyClass();
const logSpy = jest.spyOn(object, methodName);
expect(logSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

In cases where we are constructing a complex mock, we build the mock out of other named mocks:

```
const sendMock = jest.fn()
jest.mock('electron', () => ({
  ipcRenderer: {
    send: sendMock,
  },
}));
// ...
expect(sendMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to disable `@typescript-eslint/unbound-method` and enable `jest/unbound-method` rule. The latter extends the first one, so you still need to depend on `@typescript/eslint`.

```
'@typescript-eslint/unbound-method': 'off',
'jest/unbound-method': 'error',
```

Comment: Nailed it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having this problem (jest vs. typescript-eslint).  [This](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/unbound-method.md) is the eslint rule in question.

I tried a number of solutions (all around binding the mock function) and whilst I am still open to finding an elegant way to silence the linting rule without making my tests significantly less readable, I decided to disable the rule for my tests.

In my case I am mocking the electron ipcRenderer functions:

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron';

jest.mock('electron', () => ({
  ipcRenderer: {
    once: jest.fn(),
    send: jest.fn(),
    removeAllListeners: jest.fn(),
  },
}));
```

Then in a test, expecting a call to the send mock:

```
expect(ipcRenderer.send).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Binding the function directly, e.g.

```
expect(ipcRenderer.send.bind(ipcRenderer)).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

...passes the eslint rule but jest doesn't like it:

```
expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  function
Received has value: [Function bound mockConstructor]
```